# How to declare a JOGL Newt MouseEvent?

Tags: java, mouseevent, declaration, jogl

I am currently using JOGL the OpenGL Java port and I need to use the `com.jogamp.newt.event.MouseEvent`

I don't know how to declare it, I found [this documentation](https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.1.0/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/newt/event/MouseEvent.html) about it but I am still confused as to how I declare it

When I just did

```
public MouseEvent mouseEvent;
```

and tried to use `mouseEvent.getX()`

It returned a null pointer exception, I then tried

```
public MouseEvent mouseEvent = new MouseEvent();
```

But that needs some values inside the parenthesis which is what I am confused about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you know exactly what you are doing, don't create a `MouseEvent` yourself.

Rather, you need to have a class implementing the jogamp `MouseListener` and add that to your `GLWindow`, like I am doing [here](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/main/framework/Framework.java#L74) for example

Then override the following methods:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {    }

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {    }

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {    }

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {    }

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {    }

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {    }

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {    }

@Override
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseEvent e) {    }
```

And you are good to go

Comment: Thanks for the help, although now I feel like an idiot, I even had the mouse listener implemented already but didn't put two and two together

Comment: Don't worry, it happens ;)